# Inserting a deleted message to gmail with Java's API

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I want to send a `deleted` message to gmail, I'm using java libraries and I got the quick start to work and send regular email to my inbox, but I don't see where to add that property.

[image]

I'm using the example code from here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [insert message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) method has an optional parameter for that lets you set deleted.  Optional parameters have extra methods that can be used to apply them to the main request.

> deleted    boolean Mark the email as permanently deleted (not TRASH) and only visible in Google Vault to a Vault administrator. Only used for G Suite accounts. (Default: false)

Example:

```
request = service.users().messages().insert(userId, message)
request.setdeleted(True);
request.execute();
```

Link to documentation for [setDeleted](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Messages.Insert.html#setDeleted(java.lang.Boolean))